# order by in a non-numerical order

Tags: sql

I'm trying to order the results of a query in a non alpha-numerical order. For example, if the possible values of a column are '1', '2' and '3'. ORDER BY asc will display rows with '1' first, then rows with '2' and finally rows with '3'. ORDER BY desc will do the oppsite.

What if I want a different order, like 3, 1, 2 or 1, 3, 2 ? Is that possible ?

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean? what kind of order is 3,1,2?

Comment: thats not realy an order

Comment: 3,1,2 or 1,3,2 is not an ordered result.

Comment: 3,1,2 or 1, 3, 2 is not any kind of natural order...what are you needing that for?

Comment: That's exactly the idea. It is not a numercial order. It only has a functional sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use a case statement in your order by clause.

So for your 3, 1, 2 example, it would look something like this:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE <yourField>
        WHEN 3 THEN 1
        WHEN 1 THEN 2
        WHEN 2 THEN 3
        ELSE 4 END ASC
```

Comment: Or some other functional dependence to express the OP's New World Order :-)

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, however, you do not specify what order you are looking for. If you are just looking for a random order you can use `ORDER BY NEWID()`.

Comment: Thanks but i'm not looking for a random order, I want to be able to define it.

Answer (score 1):

you can add your own column named as example `my_order`
and then `order by my_order`

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have an *ordering* as much as a certain *sequence*. How would you even specify this? If we think of the collection of rows as an indexed array, then you could make a auxiliary index table:

```
position  refers_to
   1         3
   2         1
   3         2
   .         .
   .         .
```

Then you can join the tables `ON(index_table.refers_to = my_table.that_column) ORDER BY index_table.position`.